# Reverse SVG fill/nodes so image only requires one layer or object

Tags: svg, inkscape

I wanted to use a placeholder image. Unfortunately it's a mess in Inkscape.

The person who made it added a second layer (but Inkscape doesn't consider it a layer so I'm not entirely sure). The second layer adds a `background-color`. They did this because the nodes that make up the image of the cat are backwards! So when I set the fill it fills in the background behind the cat instead of the cat! So they basically added a second layer (or object?) to add color to the cat.

How do I inverse the nodes so that when I set the fill it fills in the `background-color` of the cat without the need for the second layer.

I basically want the cat to be black and the background to be transparent.

```
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   id="svg3376"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="1.0.2-2 (e86c870879, 2021-01-15)"
   width="540"
   height="540"
   sodipodi:docname="cat-silhouette-01-edited.svg">
  <metadata
     id="metadata3382">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <defs
     id="defs3380">
    <clipPath
       clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       id="clipPath26">
      <rect
         style="opacity:0.44;fill:#0000ff;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke-width:0.833368"
         id="rect28"
         width="413.07666"
         height="429.14597"
         x="-6.0507178"
         y="25.950548" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <sodipodi:namedview
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1"
     objecttolerance="10"
     gridtolerance="10"
     guidetolerance="10"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:window-width="2540"
     inkscape:window-height="1317"
     id="namedview3378"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="1.2931178"
     inkscape:cx="725.83188"
     inkscape:cy="224.01462"
     inkscape:window-x="0"
     inkscape:window-y="0"
     inkscape:window-maximized="0"
     inkscape:current-layer="svg3376"
     borderlayer="true"
     inkscape:showpageshadow="false"
     inkscape:document-rotation="0" />
  <g
     id="g2982"
     transform="matrix(1.35,0,0,1.2583131,0,-32.653915)"
     clip-path="url(#clipPath26)">
    <path
       style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1"
       d="M 0,239.5 V 0 H 200 400 V 239.5 479 H 200 0 Z"
       id="path2986"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    <path
       style="fill:#acacac"
       d="M 0,239.5 V 0 h 200 200 v 61 c 0,33.55 -0.225,61 -0.5,61 -0.76844,0 -4.07093,-3.47814 -4.82003,-5.07639 -0.84235,-1.79722 -3.01315,-5.26552 -3.70757,-5.92361 -1.17319,-1.11181 -4.45248,-9.52339 -4.17856,-10.71825 C 386.95545,99.576786 386.61795,99 386.04384,99 385.46973,99 385,97.226558 385,95.059017 385,92.891476 384.55,90.839919 384,90.5 c -0.55,-0.339919 -1.00277,-1.378976 -1.00616,-2.309017 -0.003,-0.930041 -0.67839,-2.979921 -1.5,-4.55529 C 380.67223,82.060324 380,79.922824 380,78.885693 380,77.848562 379.58575,77 379.07946,77 c -0.5063,0 -1.20317,-1.286756 -1.54859,-2.859458 -0.34543,-1.572702 -1.95618,-4.131893 -3.57946,-5.687091 C 372.32814,66.898252 371,65.229984 371,64.746187 371,64.26239 369.82159,62.321581 368.38131,60.433278 366.94103,58.544975 366.11947,57 366.55563,57 c 0.43615,0 -0.0827,-1.0125 -1.15293,-2.25 -1.07026,-1.2375 -3.26347,-4.95 -4.87379,-8.25 C 357.32717,39.938768 353.36929,35 351.31291,35 350.59081,35 350,34.325 350,33.5 c 0,-1.108158 -1.16011,-1.5 -4.44098,-1.5 -2.44254,0 -4.70695,0.430347 -5.03203,0.956326 -0.32507,0.525979 -1.20611,0.720301 -1.95786,0.431826 -0.75176,-0.288474 -1.6639,-0.04382 -2.027,0.543674 C 336.17904,34.519322 335.07827,35 334.09597,35 c -0.9823,0 -2.59088,0.889388 -3.57463,1.976419 -0.98375,1.08703 -2.1156,1.774343 -2.51522,1.527362 C 327.17516,37.990224 318,47.388776 318,48.753517 c 0,0.49382 -1.125,1.954738 -2.5,3.246483 -1.375,1.291745 -2.5,3.233078 -2.5,4.314071 0,1.080994 -0.7875,2.541278 -1.75,3.245075 -0.9625,0.703797 -1.81053,1.653406 -1.88452,2.110243 C 308.95567,64.199748 307.65178,67 306.88337,67 306.39752,67 306,67.918434 306,69.040963 c 0,1.12253 -1.38755,4.707045 -3.08343,7.965589 -1.69589,3.258544 -3.16905,6.507948 -3.27369,7.220897 -0.10464,0.712949 -1.07959,2.556536 -2.16657,4.096861 C 292.64893,95.165093 290.73164,97 288.41111,97 287.085,97 286,97.45 286,98 c 0,0.55 -1.725,1 -3.83333,1 -2.10834,0 -4.17084,0.3375 -4.58334,0.75 -0.4125,0.4125 -1.05,0.78886 -1.41666,0.83637 -1.13071,0.14648 -4.63875,1.73575 -5.16667,2.34069 -0.70814,0.81145 -4.14107,2.91519 -6.5,3.9833 -1.1,0.49806 -4.00619,2.97199 -6.45821,5.49761 -2.45201,2.52562 -5.03951,4.59203 -5.75,4.59203 -0.71048,0 -1.29179,0.40986 -1.29179,0.91079 0,0.50094 -1.9125,1.86543 -4.25,3.03221 -2.3375,1.16678 -6.05,3.20863 -8.25,4.53745 -7.14762,4.31721 -9.7684,5.51955 -12.03119,5.51955 -1.22316,0 -2.78412,0.675 -3.46881,1.5 -0.68469,0.825 -1.86479,1.5 -2.62244,1.5 -0.75766,0 -1.37756,0.39752 -1.37756,0.88337 0,0.48585 -0.7875,1.17154 -1.75,1.52375 -0.9625,0.35221 -3.775,1.75005 -6.25,3.1063 -2.475,1.35626 -4.99336,2.47057 -5.59636,2.47625 -1.82725,0.0172 -7.40364,3.09295 -7.40364,4.08357 0,0.50972 -0.90611,0.92676 -2.01357,0.92676 -1.91953,0 -5.92217,1.79182 -6.98643,3.12753 -0.275,0.34515 -2.41014,0.9468 -4.74476,1.33702 -2.33462,0.39021 -4.49868,1.12032 -4.80902,1.62246 C 179.13588,153.58916 176.01008,154 172.5,154 c -3.51008,0 -6.66008,0.45 -7,1 -0.33992,0.55 -1.49148,1 -2.55902,1 C 161.87344,156 161,155.55 161,155 c 0,-0.55 -1.09844,-1 -2.44098,-1 -1.34254,0 -2.68303,-0.39163 -2.97885,-0.87029 -0.29583,-0.47866 -4.16393,-1.0802 -8.59578,-1.33676 -4.43184,-0.25655 -8.58136,-0.98992 -9.22115,-1.62971 C 137.12346,149.52346 135.565,149 134.3,149 c -1.265,0 -2.3,-0.44468 -2.3,-0.98818 0,-0.5435 -1.8,-1.27602 -4,-1.62781 -2.2,-0.35179 -4,-1.03211 -4,-1.51182 0,-0.4797 -1.77344,-0.87219 -3.94098,-0.87219 -2.16754,0 -4.19964,-0.41851 -4.51577,-0.93001 -0.31612,-0.51151 -3.04268,-1.23836 -6.05901,-1.61523 C 106.46791,141.0779 104,140.3714 104,139.88478 104,139.39815 96.8,139 88,139 c -8.8,0 -16,0.39752 -16,0.88337 0,0.92147 -3.724599,2.4129 -5.557695,2.22544 -0.581732,-0.0595 -1.883124,1.76272 -2.891982,4.04934 -1.463775,3.31772 -1.596772,4.53783 -0.658427,6.04036 0.646722,1.03556 0.928273,2.28345 0.625669,2.77307 -0.302604,0.48962 -0.09285,1.17288 0.466123,1.51834 C 64.54266,156.83538 65,157.99148 65,159.05902 65,160.12656 65.45,161 66,161 c 0.55,0 1,0.59656 1,1.32569 0,0.72912 1.125,2.38256 2.5,3.67431 1.375,1.29175 2.5,2.94519 2.5,3.67431 0,0.72913 0.45,1.32569 1,1.32569 0.55,0 1,0.49449 1,1.09887 0,1.50268 3.195092,8.26223 4.250683,8.99277 0.470189,0.3254 0.757319,1.0004 0.638066,1.5 -0.431241,1.80663 1.376552,6.48294 2.975514,7.69691 1.740609,1.3215 3.571279,3.94222 5.037484,7.21145 0.493334,1.1 2.29226,3.32169 3.997612,4.93709 1.705353,1.6154 3.115443,3.4154 3.133535,4 0.01809,0.5846 1.818092,2.85083 4,5.03607 2.716506,2.72064 3.967106,4.84854 3.967106,6.75 0,1.52726 0.45,2.77684 1,2.77684 0.55,0 1,0.79319 1,1.76265 0,0.96946 1.08438,2.57699 2.40973,3.57229 2.32998,1.74973 4.13459,5.84373 3.70933,8.41506 -0.1137,0.6875 0.179,1.25 0.65046,1.25 0.47145,0 1.47517,1.575 2.23048,3.5 0.75531,1.925 1.87298,3.5 2.4837,3.5 1.41308,0 8.03068,6.9298 8.8476,9.26501 0.3396,0.97075 1.75398,2.19711 3.14307,2.72525 2.37013,0.90112 3.1664,3.2387 2.61759,7.68433 -0.0797,0.64603 0.31693,1.46009 0.88152,1.80902 0.56459,0.34893 1.02652,3.53287 1.02652,7.07541 0,3.54254 0.39752,6.44098 0.88337,6.44098 1.00304,0 2.28519,3.44015 2.48351,6.66357 0.0732,1.18996 0.47062,2.50246 0.88312,2.91667 0.4125,0.4142 0.75,1.76559 0.75,3.00309 0,1.2375 0.5625,2.5125 1.25,2.83334 1,0.46666 1,0.7 0,1.16666 -1.51004,0.70469 -1.72612,11.00438 -0.25,11.91667 0.55,0.33992 1,2.33638 1,4.43657 0,2.17431 0.64589,4.35458 1.5,5.06343 0.825,0.68469 1.51001,2.42729 1.52224,3.87244 0.0122,1.44516 0.90222,3.75256 1.97776,5.12756 1.07554,1.375 1.96553,2.98406 1.97776,3.57569 0.0122,0.59162 1.12733,2.11386 2.47799,3.38274 1.35067,1.26888 2.42238,2.58482 2.38158,2.92431 C 150.59531,336.89678 151.18375,338 152.5,338 c 0.825,0 1.5,0.45 1.5,1 0,0.55 0.57942,1 1.28759,1 1.74553,0 10.3439,8.97716 11.13355,11.62401 0.89127,2.98749 10.72668,12.74372 14.79184,14.67277 1.86591,0.88543 4.22607,2.53088 5.24478,3.65655 1.01872,1.12567 2.65591,2.04667 3.63821,2.04667 0.9823,0 2.04271,0.41538 2.35648,0.92306 0.31377,0.50769 1.91532,1.21844 3.55902,1.57946 1.64369,0.36101 2.98853,1.07064 2.98853,1.57694 0,0.50629 1.09844,0.92054 2.44098,0.92054 1.34254,0 2.70695,0.43035 3.03203,0.95633 0.32507,0.52598 1.29704,0.6854 2.15994,0.35428 0.86289,-0.33113 1.86098,-0.17553 2.21797,0.34578 0.357,0.5213 2.35483,1.74164 4.43964,2.71188 2.08481,0.97023 5.28255,3.07404 7.10609,4.67514 1.82355,1.60109 3.51753,2.70908 3.76441,2.4622 0.24688,-0.24689 3.56207,2.68836 7.36709,6.52276 3.80502,3.83439 7.49278,6.97163 8.19503,6.97163 0.70225,0 1.27682,0.39752 1.27682,0.88337 0,0.48585 0.7875,1.17154 1.75,1.52375 0.9625,0.35221 3.775,1.75005 6.25,3.1063 2.475,1.35626 5.0625,2.47057 5.75,2.47625 0.6875,0.006 1.25,0.35417 1.25,0.77443 0,0.42025 1.6875,1.54733 3.75,2.50461 4.46584,2.07276 7.52448,3.9239 8.35588,5.05712 0.33323,0.4542 2.48171,1.07742 4.77438,1.38494 2.29267,0.30751 4.40909,0.94839 4.70314,1.42417 0.78063,1.2631 5.82424,1.05742 7.17422,-0.29256 0.77551,-0.77551 1.58421,-0.83262 2.45,-0.17302 0.71081,0.54153 3.98105,1.07363 7.26719,1.18243 3.28615,0.10881 6.41365,0.63667 6.95,1.17302 1.31551,1.31551 6.91068,1.2397 8.26232,-0.11194 0.78285,-0.78285 1.2752,-0.78285 1.75902,0 0.36954,0.59792 2.45143,1.08713 4.62644,1.08713 3.8068,0 4.67153,-0.25607 9.71809,-2.87775 1.25987,-0.6545 2.69128,-0.94242 3.1809,-0.63982 0.48962,0.30261 1.17288,0.0928 1.51834,-0.46612 0.34546,-0.55897 2.18117,-1.01631 4.07935,-1.01631 2.26803,0 5.07619,-1.12307 8.19099,-3.27583 3.91765,-2.70765 5.12999,-3.10013 6.98974,-2.26287 1.2375,0.55713 2.25,1.35625 2.25,1.77583 0,0.80961 1.17404,2.01878 7.78005,8.01287 2.27305,2.0625 4.61208,3.75 5.19783,3.75 0.58575,0 1.53508,1.03173 2.10963,2.29273 0.57455,1.26099 2.70241,3.06307 4.72856,4.00461 5.03077,2.33775 7.28262,3.80859 9.87901,6.45266 1.21518,1.2375 2.58958,2.25 3.05422,2.25 0.46464,0 2.60246,1.8 4.7507,4 2.14824,2.2 4.41113,4 5.02863,4 0.61751,0 2.10118,1.0415 3.29706,2.31445 1.98684,2.1149 2.17431,3.36512 2.17431,14.5 V 479 H 200 0 Z M 221,331 c 0,-0.55 -1.32344,-1 -2.94098,-1 -1.61754,0 -3.18829,-0.40015 -3.49055,-0.88922 -0.30227,-0.48907 -1.79132,-1.19444 -3.30902,-1.56748 C 207.86349,326.70859 201,320.22667 201,317.85421 c 0,-0.95694 -0.83494,-3.22811 -1.85542,-5.04705 -1.90458,-3.39477 -2.14543,-7.4375 -0.70065,-11.76052 C 200.06387,296.19952 205.38171,293 211.81802,293 h 4.88839 l -0.47199,4.91218 c -0.38165,3.9719 0.0771,6.06442 2.39679,10.93175 2.90332,6.09203 5.56436,8.06858 8.06675,5.99177 C 228.2184,313.57386 228.4718,307 227,307 c -0.55,0 -1,-1.05526 -1,-2.34501 0,-1.28976 -0.90334,-3.16253 -2.00743,-4.16171 -1.10409,-0.99919 -2.6446,-3.09393 -3.42336,-4.65499 L 219.15329,293 h 5.93692 c 5.57069,0 9.49826,1.22758 11.10542,3.47104 0.38259,0.53407 0.95712,0.70955 1.27672,0.38995 1.10872,-1.10873 8.52765,6.64362 8.52765,8.91089 0,1.22547 0.45,2.22812 1,2.22812 0.55,0 1,1.125 1,2.5 0,1.375 -0.45,2.5 -1,2.5 -0.55,0 -1,0.83086 -1,1.84636 0,3.70729 -5.9812,12.15364 -8.60648,12.15364 -0.65777,0 -6.93155,2.66071 -9.62995,4.08407 C 225.44382,332.30769 221,332.25246 221,331 Z M 336.62407,289.20075 C 336.21591,288.54034 334.58508,288 333,288 c -1.58508,0 -3.16462,-0.45734 -3.51008,-1.01631 -0.34546,-0.55897 -0.97389,-0.80261 -1.39651,-0.54142 -0.86682,0.53573 -6.93834,-5.76519 -8.84453,-9.1787 -1.46513,-2.62369 -1.64572,-6.90028 -0.32582,-7.71602 0.50769,-0.31377 1.21844,-1.91532 1.57946,-3.55902 C 320.86353,264.34484 321.57316,263 322.07946,263 322.58575,263 323,262.40344 323,261.67431 c 0,-1.41522 3.12542,-4.40982 6.64608,-6.36788 1.79931,-1.00072 2.43028,-0.87954 3.90499,0.75 1.01449,1.121 1.27008,1.94357 0.60392,1.94357 -0.63525,0 -1.15499,1.125 -1.15499,2.5 0,1.375 0.45,2.5 1,2.5 0.55,0 1,0.58367 1,1.29705 0,1.55317 7.12314,8.70295 8.67052,8.70295 0.59741,0 1.52385,-1.72418 2.05875,-3.83152 0.79819,-3.14463 0.60652,-4.62363 -1.06916,-8.25 -1.12294,-2.43016 -3.12244,-5.44804 -4.44335,-6.7064 -2.68079,-2.55385 -2.34126,-5.10525 0.78829,-5.92365 1.09722,-0.28693 1.99495,-0.91921 1.99495,-1.40506 0,-1.50416 9.51531,-0.97188 12.91127,0.72225 2.80122,1.39743 5.05369,4.60033 5.55181,7.89438 0.0832,0.55 0.51738,1.80374 0.96491,2.78609 0.71638,1.57249 0.35517,9.32664 -0.64259,13.79469 -0.65746,2.94417 -9.13244,12.97095 -12.46966,14.7529 C 348.1144,287.47516 345.1144,288 342.64907,288 c -2.59897,0 -4.65058,0.50453 -4.88265,1.20075 -0.31144,0.93432 -0.56491,0.93432 -1.14235,0 z"
       id="path2984"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh. Editing Inkscape or Illustrator generated SVG is like clearing a toilet blockage with your hands.

Anyway - here is a version that works with all the crap cleaned out. It uses a filter to do the inversion - I wasn't touching that path definition!

```html
<svg
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   width="540px"
   height="540px">
  
  <defs>
    <filter id="invert" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
        <feComponentTransfer in="SourceAlpha" result="inverted-input">
          <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="1 0"/>
        </feComponentTransfer>
        <feFlood flood-color="black"/>
        <feComposite operator="in" in="inverted-input"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>

<g filter="url(#invert)" transform="scale(1.2) translate(51)">
    <path fill="white"
       d="M 0,239.5 V 0 h 200 200 v 61 c 0,33.55 -0.225,61 -0.5,61 -0.76844,0 -4.07093,-3.47814 -4.82003,-5.07639 -0.84235,-1.79722 -3.01315,-5.26552 -3.70757,-5.92361 -1.17319,-1.11181 -4.45248,-9.52339 -4.17856,-10.71825 C 386.95545,99.576786 386.61795,99 386.04384,99 385.46973,99 385,97.226558 385,95.059017 385,92.891476 384.55,90.839919 384,90.5 c -0.55,-0.339919 -1.00277,-1.378976 -1.00616,-2.309017 -0.003,-0.930041 -0.67839,-2.979921 -1.5,-4.55529 C 380.67223,82.060324 380,79.922824 380,78.885693 380,77.848562 379.58575,77 379.07946,77 c -0.5063,0 -1.20317,-1.286756 -1.54859,-2.859458 -0.34543,-1.572702 -1.95618,-4.131893 -3.57946,-5.687091 C 372.32814,66.898252 371,65.229984 371,64.746187 371,64.26239 369.82159,62.321581 368.38131,60.433278 366.94103,58.544975 366.11947,57 366.55563,57 c 0.43615,0 -0.0827,-1.0125 -1.15293,-2.25 -1.07026,-1.2375 -3.26347,-4.95 -4.87379,-8.25 C 357.32717,39.938768 353.36929,35 351.31291,35 350.59081,35 350,34.325 350,33.5 c 0,-1.108158 -1.16011,-1.5 -4.44098,-1.5 -2.44254,0 -4.70695,0.430347 -5.03203,0.956326 -0.32507,0.525979 -1.20611,0.720301 -1.95786,0.431826 -0.75176,-0.288474 -1.6639,-0.04382 -2.027,0.543674 C 336.17904,34.519322 335.07827,35 334.09597,35 c -0.9823,0 -2.59088,0.889388 -3.57463,1.976419 -0.98375,1.08703 -2.1156,1.774343 -2.51522,1.527362 C 327.17516,37.990224 318,47.388776 318,48.753517 c 0,0.49382 -1.125,1.954738 -2.5,3.246483 -1.375,1.291745 -2.5,3.233078 -2.5,4.314071 0,1.080994 -0.7875,2.541278 -1.75,3.245075 -0.9625,0.703797 -1.81053,1.653406 -1.88452,2.110243 C 308.95567,64.199748 307.65178,67 306.88337,67 306.39752,67 306,67.918434 306,69.040963 c 0,1.12253 -1.38755,4.707045 -3.08343,7.965589 -1.69589,3.258544 -3.16905,6.507948 -3.27369,7.220897 -0.10464,0.712949 -1.07959,2.556536 -2.16657,4.096861 C 292.64893,95.165093 290.73164,97 288.41111,97 287.085,97 286,97.45 286,98 c 0,0.55 -1.725,1 -3.83333,1 -2.10834,0 -4.17084,0.3375 -4.58334,0.75 -0.4125,0.4125 -1.05,0.78886 -1.41666,0.83637 -1.13071,0.14648 -4.63875,1.73575 -5.16667,2.34069 -0.70814,0.81145 -4.14107,2.91519 -6.5,3.9833 -1.1,0.49806 -4.00619,2.97199 -6.45821,5.49761 -2.45201,2.52562 -5.03951,4.59203 -5.75,4.59203 -0.71048,0 -1.29179,0.40986 -1.29179,0.91079 0,0.50094 -1.9125,1.86543 -4.25,3.03221 -2.3375,1.16678 -6.05,3.20863 -8.25,4.53745 -7.14762,4.31721 -9.7684,5.51955 -12.03119,5.51955 -1.22316,0 -2.78412,0.675 -3.46881,1.5 -0.68469,0.825 -1.86479,1.5 -2.62244,1.5 -0.75766,0 -1.37756,0.39752 -1.37756,0.88337 0,0.48585 -0.7875,1.17154 -1.75,1.52375 -0.9625,0.35221 -3.775,1.75005 -6.25,3.1063 -2.475,1.35626 -4.99336,2.47057 -5.59636,2.47625 -1.82725,0.0172 -7.40364,3.09295 -7.40364,4.08357 0,0.50972 -0.90611,0.92676 -2.01357,0.92676 -1.91953,0 -5.92217,1.79182 -6.98643,3.12753 -0.275,0.34515 -2.41014,0.9468 -4.74476,1.33702 -2.33462,0.39021 -4.49868,1.12032 -4.80902,1.62246 C 179.13588,153.58916 176.01008,154 172.5,154 c -3.51008,0 -6.66008,0.45 -7,1 -0.33992,0.55 -1.49148,1 -2.55902,1 C 161.87344,156 161,155.55 161,155 c 0,-0.55 -1.09844,-1 -2.44098,-1 -1.34254,0 -2.68303,-0.39163 -2.97885,-0.87029 -0.29583,-0.47866 -4.16393,-1.0802 -8.59578,-1.33676 -4.43184,-0.25655 -8.58136,-0.98992 -9.22115,-1.62971 C 137.12346,149.52346 135.565,149 134.3,149 c -1.265,0 -2.3,-0.44468 -2.3,-0.98818 0,-0.5435 -1.8,-1.27602 -4,-1.62781 -2.2,-0.35179 -4,-1.03211 -4,-1.51182 0,-0.4797 -1.77344,-0.87219 -3.94098,-0.87219 -2.16754,0 -4.19964,-0.41851 -4.51577,-0.93001 -0.31612,-0.51151 -3.04268,-1.23836 -6.05901,-1.61523 C 106.46791,141.0779 104,140.3714 104,139.88478 104,139.39815 96.8,139 88,139 c -8.8,0 -16,0.39752 -16,0.88337 0,0.92147 -3.724599,2.4129 -5.557695,2.22544 -0.581732,-0.0595 -1.883124,1.76272 -2.891982,4.04934 -1.463775,3.31772 -1.596772,4.53783 -0.658427,6.04036 0.646722,1.03556 0.928273,2.28345 0.625669,2.77307 -0.302604,0.48962 -0.09285,1.17288 0.466123,1.51834 C 64.54266,156.83538 65,157.99148 65,159.05902 65,160.12656 65.45,161 66,161 c 0.55,0 1,0.59656 1,1.32569 0,0.72912 1.125,2.38256 2.5,3.67431 1.375,1.29175 2.5,2.94519 2.5,3.67431 0,0.72913 0.45,1.32569 1,1.32569 0.55,0 1,0.49449 1,1.09887 0,1.50268 3.195092,8.26223 4.250683,8.99277 0.470189,0.3254 0.757319,1.0004 0.638066,1.5 -0.431241,1.80663 1.376552,6.48294 2.975514,7.69691 1.740609,1.3215 3.571279,3.94222 5.037484,7.21145 0.493334,1.1 2.29226,3.32169 3.997612,4.93709 1.705353,1.6154 3.115443,3.4154 3.133535,4 0.01809,0.5846 1.818092,2.85083 4,5.03607 2.716506,2.72064 3.967106,4.84854 3.967106,6.75 0,1.52726 0.45,2.77684 1,2.77684 0.55,0 1,0.79319 1,1.76265 0,0.96946 1.08438,2.57699 2.40973,3.57229 2.32998,1.74973 4.13459,5.84373 3.70933,8.41506 -0.1137,0.6875 0.179,1.25 0.65046,1.25 0.47145,0 1.47517,1.575 2.23048,3.5 0.75531,1.925 1.87298,3.5 2.4837,3.5 1.41308,0 8.03068,6.9298 8.8476,9.26501 0.3396,0.97075 1.75398,2.19711 3.14307,2.72525 2.37013,0.90112 3.1664,3.2387 2.61759,7.68433 -0.0797,0.64603 0.31693,1.46009 0.88152,1.80902 0.56459,0.34893 1.02652,3.53287 1.02652,7.07541 0,3.54254 0.39752,6.44098 0.88337,6.44098 1.00304,0 2.28519,3.44015 2.48351,6.66357 0.0732,1.18996 0.47062,2.50246 0.88312,2.91667 0.4125,0.4142 0.75,1.76559 0.75,3.00309 0,1.2375 0.5625,2.5125 1.25,2.83334 1,0.46666 1,0.7 0,1.16666 -1.51004,0.70469 -1.72612,11.00438 -0.25,11.91667 0.55,0.33992 1,2.33638 1,4.43657 0,2.17431 0.64589,4.35458 1.5,5.06343 0.825,0.68469 1.51001,2.42729 1.52224,3.87244 0.0122,1.44516 0.90222,3.75256 1.97776,5.12756 1.07554,1.375 1.96553,2.98406 1.97776,3.57569 0.0122,0.59162 1.12733,2.11386 2.47799,3.38274 1.35067,1.26888 2.42238,2.58482 2.38158,2.92431 C 150.59531,336.89678 151.18375,338 152.5,338 c 0.825,0 1.5,0.45 1.5,1 0,0.55 0.57942,1 1.28759,1 1.74553,0 10.3439,8.97716 11.13355,11.62401 0.89127,2.98749 10.72668,12.74372 14.79184,14.67277 1.86591,0.88543 4.22607,2.53088 5.24478,3.65655 1.01872,1.12567 2.65591,2.04667 3.63821,2.04667 0.9823,0 2.04271,0.41538 2.35648,0.92306 0.31377,0.50769 1.91532,1.21844 3.55902,1.57946 1.64369,0.36101 2.98853,1.07064 2.98853,1.57694 0,0.50629 1.09844,0.92054 2.44098,0.92054 1.34254,0 2.70695,0.43035 3.03203,0.95633 0.32507,0.52598 1.29704,0.6854 2.15994,0.35428 0.86289,-0.33113 1.86098,-0.17553 2.21797,0.34578 0.357,0.5213 2.35483,1.74164 4.43964,2.71188 2.08481,0.97023 5.28255,3.07404 7.10609,4.67514 1.82355,1.60109 3.51753,2.70908 3.76441,2.4622 0.24688,-0.24689 3.56207,2.68836 7.36709,6.52276 3.80502,3.83439 7.49278,6.97163 8.19503,6.97163 0.70225,0 1.27682,0.39752 1.27682,0.88337 0,0.48585 0.7875,1.17154 1.75,1.52375 0.9625,0.35221 3.775,1.75005 6.25,3.1063 2.475,1.35626 5.0625,2.47057 5.75,2.47625 0.6875,0.006 1.25,0.35417 1.25,0.77443 0,0.42025 1.6875,1.54733 3.75,2.50461 4.46584,2.07276 7.52448,3.9239 8.35588,5.05712 0.33323,0.4542 2.48171,1.07742 4.77438,1.38494 2.29267,0.30751 4.40909,0.94839 4.70314,1.42417 0.78063,1.2631 5.82424,1.05742 7.17422,-0.29256 0.77551,-0.77551 1.58421,-0.83262 2.45,-0.17302 0.71081,0.54153 3.98105,1.07363 7.26719,1.18243 3.28615,0.10881 6.41365,0.63667 6.95,1.17302 1.31551,1.31551 6.91068,1.2397 8.26232,-0.11194 0.78285,-0.78285 1.2752,-0.78285 1.75902,0 0.36954,0.59792 2.45143,1.08713 4.62644,1.08713 3.8068,0 4.67153,-0.25607 9.71809,-2.87775 1.25987,-0.6545 2.69128,-0.94242 3.1809,-0.63982 0.48962,0.30261 1.17288,0.0928 1.51834,-0.46612 0.34546,-0.55897 2.18117,-1.01631 4.07935,-1.01631 2.26803,0 5.07619,-1.12307 8.19099,-3.27583 3.91765,-2.70765 5.12999,-3.10013 6.98974,-2.26287 1.2375,0.55713 2.25,1.35625 2.25,1.77583 0,0.80961 1.17404,2.01878 7.78005,8.01287 2.27305,2.0625 4.61208,3.75 5.19783,3.75 0.58575,0 1.53508,1.03173 2.10963,2.29273 0.57455,1.26099 2.70241,3.06307 4.72856,4.00461 5.03077,2.33775 7.28262,3.80859 9.87901,6.45266 1.21518,1.2375 2.58958,2.25 3.05422,2.25 0.46464,0 2.60246,1.8 4.7507,4 2.14824,2.2 4.41113,4 5.02863,4 0.61751,0 2.10118,1.0415 3.29706,2.31445 1.98684,2.1149 2.17431,3.36512 2.17431,14.5 V 479 H 200 0 Z M 221,331 c 0,-0.55 -1.32344,-1 -2.94098,-1 -1.61754,0 -3.18829,-0.40015 -3.49055,-0.88922 -0.30227,-0.48907 -1.79132,-1.19444 -3.30902,-1.56748 C 207.86349,326.70859 201,320.22667 201,317.85421 c 0,-0.95694 -0.83494,-3.22811 -1.85542,-5.04705 -1.90458,-3.39477 -2.14543,-7.4375 -0.70065,-11.76052 C 200.06387,296.19952 205.38171,293 211.81802,293 h 4.88839 l -0.47199,4.91218 c -0.38165,3.9719 0.0771,6.06442 2.39679,10.93175 2.90332,6.09203 5.56436,8.06858 8.06675,5.99177 C 228.2184,313.57386 228.4718,307 227,307 c -0.55,0 -1,-1.05526 -1,-2.34501 0,-1.28976 -0.90334,-3.16253 -2.00743,-4.16171 -1.10409,-0.99919 -2.6446,-3.09393 -3.42336,-4.65499 L 219.15329,293 h 5.93692 c 5.57069,0 9.49826,1.22758 11.10542,3.47104 0.38259,0.53407 0.95712,0.70955 1.27672,0.38995 1.10872,-1.10873 8.52765,6.64362 8.52765,8.91089 0,1.22547 0.45,2.22812 1,2.22812 0.55,0 1,1.125 1,2.5 0,1.375 -0.45,2.5 -1,2.5 -0.55,0 -1,0.83086 -1,1.84636 0,3.70729 -5.9812,12.15364 -8.60648,12.15364 -0.65777,0 -6.93155,2.66071 -9.62995,4.08407 C 225.44382,332.30769 221,332.25246 221,331 Z M 336.62407,289.20075 C 336.21591,288.54034 334.58508,288 333,288 c -1.58508,0 -3.16462,-0.45734 -3.51008,-1.01631 -0.34546,-0.55897 -0.97389,-0.80261 -1.39651,-0.54142 -0.86682,0.53573 -6.93834,-5.76519 -8.84453,-9.1787 -1.46513,-2.62369 -1.64572,-6.90028 -0.32582,-7.71602 0.50769,-0.31377 1.21844,-1.91532 1.57946,-3.55902 C 320.86353,264.34484 321.57316,263 322.07946,263 322.58575,263 323,262.40344 323,261.67431 c 0,-1.41522 3.12542,-4.40982 6.64608,-6.36788 1.79931,-1.00072 2.43028,-0.87954 3.90499,0.75 1.01449,1.121 1.27008,1.94357 0.60392,1.94357 -0.63525,0 -1.15499,1.125 -1.15499,2.5 0,1.375 0.45,2.5 1,2.5 0.55,0 1,0.58367 1,1.29705 0,1.55317 7.12314,8.70295 8.67052,8.70295 0.59741,0 1.52385,-1.72418 2.05875,-3.83152 0.79819,-3.14463 0.60652,-4.62363 -1.06916,-8.25 -1.12294,-2.43016 -3.12244,-5.44804 -4.44335,-6.7064 -2.68079,-2.55385 -2.34126,-5.10525 0.78829,-5.92365 1.09722,-0.28693 1.99495,-0.91921 1.99495,-1.40506 0,-1.50416 9.51531,-0.97188 12.91127,0.72225 2.80122,1.39743 5.05369,4.60033 5.55181,7.89438 0.0832,0.55 0.51738,1.80374 0.96491,2.78609 0.71638,1.57249 0.35517,9.32664 -0.64259,13.79469 -0.65746,2.94417 -9.13244,12.97095 -12.46966,14.7529 C 348.1144,287.47516 345.1144,288 342.64907,288 c -2.59897,0 -4.65058,0.50453 -4.88265,1.20075 -0.31144,0.93432 -0.56491,0.93432 -1.14235,0 z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I agree! The site https://www.svgminify.com/ helped me really clean out a lot of the garbage. I was hoping more for a *how-to-fish* sort of answer though this is fine too I suppose; I'm only occasionally relying on SVG to compensate for odd browser issues. Only thing is, when I edit this file in Inkscape I can't select and move anything around? What gives? Thank you for the post.

Comment: Well the how-to-fish version, is that it's very difficult to go into the path and redefine it in a way that encloses the cat vs. the cat's negative space. It's not impossible, but you have to find the long straight lines that define the rectangular edges and redraw them. That's a very long path definition, so I wasn't going to go treasure hunting to find the commands that do that. When I cleaned out the crap, I cleaned out all the Inkscape stuff that makes the SVG into an Inkscape file - sorry.

Comment: It's cool, I figured it was going to be a mess. Once my business gets big enough I'll try to make it one of my pet projects to fix. Thanks again.